# replace text hyperlink with id attribute value and make it unclickable

Tags: javascript, html

What am I trying to accomplish is to display a text message on a web page after I click a text. The new text should replace the text that I clicked. The new text should be the value of the id attribute. The hyperlink is meant to go away after the first click (and become unclickable).

Here is one of my attempts:

```
<a href="#" onclick id="Ana"> Apasa textul 1</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#id").on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("Ana").innerHTML = "<span> Ana </span>";
});
</script>
```

The tag that should be used to replace the `<a>` tag is `<span>`.

I expect to display `Ana` after I click  `Apasa textul 1`

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Display where? and look like what?  You want a tooltip? a modal? another page? a text replacement? You want the new text appended to the old text?  Your question is Unclear, I completely understand the downvotes.  It doesn't look like you need ajax here.  Is there some requirement that requires ajax in your actual project?

Comment: I want the new text appended to the old text

Comment: Do you _actually_ need an ajax request?  By your post, you just want to append the `id` attribute's value to the end of the hyperlink text.  ...or do you want it _after_ the hyperlink?  Do we need to see more of the html here?

Comment: Ajax request is not necessary, I want to append the ID attribute value to the end of the hyperlink text, thx you

Comment: Please update your post to show your exact expected source code.  `<a href="#" onclick id="Ana"> Apasa texul 1</a> Ana` or `<a href="#" onclick id="Ana"> Apasa texul 1 Ana</a>`  (I only understand English.)  What is the desired behavior if the hyperlink is clicked a second time?  Is the hyperlink meant to go away after the first click (and become unclickable)?

Comment: When the new html looks like `<a href="#" onclick id="Ana"> Apasa texul 1 Ana</a>` and the user clicks the link, should it become `<a href="#" onclick id="Ana"> Apasa texul 1 Ana Ana</a>` ?  Does the tag need to remain as a hyperlink for any reason?

Comment: What tag should be use to replace the `<a>` tag?  A `<span>` perhaps?

Comment: Thx for helping me, yes <span>

Comment: You should add this requirement to your question as well, so that you don't continue to receive incorrect answers.

Comment: even though I  simplify the question as much as I could not so many ppl like the question

Comment: People don't often return to a question after downvoting.  It was initially a downvote worthy question.  The inclusion of ajax was unnecessary and added confusion to the requirements.  Now you have removed your coding attempt, but some upvoters (including myself) expect a coding attempt to be posted in every question.  Like you, I am very surprised that my post isn't receiving more love.  Is there anything about my answer that doesn't satisfy or that needs further explanation? @rusu

Comment: your post is great (the best I will say), just waiting for a little more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be quite a few different ways to do this, but if you want to employ an inline function call, you could declare a custom function called `swapTag()` (or whatever you like) which will generate a new `<span>` tag, then fill it with the original tags `id` value, then replace the original dom element with the newly generated element.

```js
function swapTag(el) {
  let newEl = document.createElement('span');
  newEl.innerHTML = el.id;
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="Ana" onclick="swapTag(this);">Apasa texul 1</a>
```

Although you have stated that you wish to replace the `<a>` tag with a `<span>` tag, if you want to replace the `<a>` with pure text, this will work too:

```
<a href="#" id="Ana" onclick="this.outerHTML = this.id;">Apasa texul 1</a>
```

There isn't a great deal of context to the question, so I don't know how much utility your project actually requires.  Inline function calls may be an ugly choice -- using a listener may be a cleaner way.

---

I'll add an alternative that will use Jquery and an event listener (so that you you aren't muddying up your dom with inline function calls ...again, it is hard to give you a "perfect" answer because we don't know much about your application).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="#"][id]').click(function(){
        let oldEl = this,
            newEl = document.createElement('span');
        newEl.innerHTML = oldEl.id;
        oldEl.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, oldEl);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="Ana">Apasa texul 1</a>
<a href="#">Apasa texul 1</a>
<a href="#" id="Someone else">Apasa texul 1</a>
```

And again, if you want to just swap the `<a>` tag for text, this is the jquery-listener version  (listening for the click of an `<a>` tag with an `href` value of `#` and an `id` attribute containing anything):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="#"][id]').click(function(){
        this.outerHTML = this.id;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On you PHP you must do this (put this code in the top of the page):

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['name'])) 
  {
    echo $_POST['name'];
    exit;
  }
 ?>
```

On JS:

```
$('#Ana').click(function()
{
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
     $.ajax( 
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data:  {'name':name},
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success:function(result) 
                    {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                }
            )
});
```

The alert will show you the echoed value by PHP. From there do as you please... something like `$('p').html(result);`

Because you are doing an ajax call, you cannot rely on that inline code you wrote, since the page is not being entirely refreshed. That code executes when you first load the page, but because when that happens you are not passing parameters via POST (normally) in the initial statements "else" is always executed.

When calling ajax if you do not perform "exit;" in my code above, you would receive the entire page in the result. That's why the code must be at the top of the page, and an exit must be called after.

Comment: even i perform "exit"i still recevie the entire page :(

Comment: try add dataType: "text" to the ajax call

Comment: humm.. pass the data like this  data:  {'name':name},

Comment: the if(isset... is at the very top of the index.php?

Comment: set cache:false, this is strange, must be cache.

Comment: try doing var_dump($_POST) outside and prior to the if statement to see whats inside $_POST.

Comment: i try it just display array(0) { }..and still return the entire page :(

Comment: are you sure your code "isset" in on your index.php ?! aren't you targeting the wrong page?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all those stuff.

If i understand the whole, you want, when the link is clicked, to:

- perform an AJAX call
- replace the whole link by its ID property, no matter the call does

```html
<a href="#" onclick="performAjaxCall(this); this.outerHTML = this.id; return false;" id="Ana"> Apasa texul 1</a>
```

is the fastest way, considering your AJAX call would be in `performAjaxCall()` .

Answer (score 0):

```php
<a href="#" onclick id="Ana"> Apasa texul 1</a>
<p><?php if(isset($_POST['name']))echo $_POST['name'];else echo 'rusu';?></p> /** 2nd line **/
```

The `2nd line` isn't meant to be executed after an `AJAX` request, it only gets executed when the entire page is requested normally.

To have the wanted results you may :

- In the `JavaScript` part, when attaching the click handler you'll need to prevent the default behavior of the `a` element (redirects to wathever the `href` attribute is, if it's `#` the page gets scrolled to the top in most cases). Also, to distinguish that the request is an `AJAx` request you may use a `POST` variable, set to `1` for example, to check it in the server side.
- In the `PHP` part, check if the `$_POST['isajax']` (the variable that should tell us we have an `AJAX` request) and `$_POST['name']` are set and `$_POST['isajax']` equals `1` then `echo` the `$_POST['name']` and halt the script. Also, these checks are likely to be the put in the top of the `PHP` file.

The `JavaScript` part may look like :

```
$('#Ana').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); /** prevents the link's default behavior **/
  var name = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: {
      isajax: 1, /** means we have an ajax request, it's not that  **/
      name: name
    },
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response)
    }
  })
});
```

and the `PHP` part (top of `index.php` page) ould look like :

```php
if(isset($_POST['isajax'], $_POST['name']) && $_POST['isajax'] == 1) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
    exit; /** no further lines are executed **/
}
```